# Error while compiling ros drivers for velodyne on ROS Indigo

Tags: ros, velodyne-driver, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

System Config: Ubuntu 14.04 and
ROS Indigo

As mentioned here, http://answers.ros.org/question/226594/how-do-i-build-ros-vlp16-velodyne-driver-for-indigo-using-catkin/
I have followed those steps to install ROS drivers from Velodyne to work with VLP 16.

However, when i run

```
catkin_make
```

I get the following errors

[ 61%] Built target ringcolors_node

[ 63%] Linking CXX shared library /home/iirav/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libvelodyne_rawdata.so

[ 70%] Built target ringcolors_nodelet

/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libyaml-cpp.a(conversion.cpp.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.bss' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

/usr/local/lib/libyaml-cpp.a: error adding symbols: Bad value

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

make[2]: *** [/home/iirav/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libvelodyne_rawdata.so] Error 1

make[1]: *** [velodyne/velodyne_pointcloud/src/lib/CMakeFiles/velodyne_rawdata.dir/all] Error 2

make: *** [all] Error 2

Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed

Any suggestions pls
?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260535/error-while-compiling-ros-drivers-for-velodyne-on-ros-indigo/) by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1935 on 2017-04-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This error arised because of some broken dependencies or some inconsistencies with my compiling of libyaml-cpp package.

To solve this error, I had to recomplile libyaml-cpp package.

Steps for that are

ccmake ..

Then

> set the option BUILD_SHARED_LIBS to
> ON

Then generate, make and install.

After this, just running catkin_make compiled the velodyne ROS driver successfully!

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2017-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0